# regarding performing marriage of son within one year if death of father in law

Tags: dharma-shastras

I had performed the death rituals of my father in law since he does not have sons and my wife being his elder daughter.  Now I have a doubt that whether I can perform my elder son's marriage with in one year.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate as the OP has performed rituals of a not-so-near relative. The question is about what should be done when such rituals are _performed_, not when a near member has passed away.